# numpy: how interpolate between two arrays for various timesteps?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I'm looking for a way to do a simple linear interpolation between two `numpy` arrays that represent a start and endpoint in time.

The two arrays have the same length:

```
fst = np.random.random_integers(5, size=(10.))
>>> array([4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2])
snd = np.random.random_integers(5, size=(10.))
>>> array([1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3])
```

Between my start and endpoint there are 3 timesteps. How can I interpolate between `fst` and `snd`? I want to be able, taking the first entry of `fst` and `snd` as an example, to retrieve the value of each timestep like

```
np.interp(1, [1,5], [4,1])    
np.interp(2, [1,5], [4,1])
...
# that is
np.interp([1,2,3,4,5], [1,5], [4,1])
>>> array([ 4.  ,  3.25,  2.5 ,  1.75,  1.  ])
```

But than not just for the first entry but over the whole array.

Obviously, this won't do it:

```
np.interp(1, [1,5], [fst,snd])
```

Well I know I get there in a loop, e.g.

```
[np.interp(2, [1,5], [item,snd[idx]]) for idx,item in enumerate(fst)]
>>> [3.25, 3.25, 1.5, 3.25, 1.0, 4.25, 3.5, 2.75, 4.75, 2.25]
```

but I believe when you are lopping over numpy arrays you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The facilities in [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) allow this to be done quite easily if you form your samples into a 2D matrix. In your case, you can construct a 2xN array, and construct an interpolation function that operates down the columns:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
fst = np.array([4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2])
snd = np.array([1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3])
linfit = interp1d([1,5], np.vstack([fst, snd]), axis=0)
```

You can then generate an interpolated vector at any time of interest. For example `linfit(2)` produces:

```
array([ 3.25,  3.25,  1.5 ,  3.25,  1.  ,  4.25,  3.5 ,  2.75,  4.75,  2.25])
```

or you can invoke `linfit()` with a vector of time values, e.g. `linfit([1,2,3])` gives:

```
array([[ 4.  ,  4.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  1.  ,  4.  ,  3.  ,  2.  ,  5.  ,  2.  ],
       [ 3.25,  3.25,  1.5 ,  3.25,  1.  ,  4.25,  3.5 ,  2.75,  4.75,           2.25],
       [ 2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.  ,  3.5 ,  1.  ,  4.5 ,  4.  ,  3.5 ,  4.5 , 2.5 ]])
```

If you're only doing linear interpolation, you could also just do something like:

```
((5-t)/(5-1)) * fst + ((t-1)/(5-1)) * snd
```

to directly compute the interpolated vector at any time t.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is similar but uses simpler notation:

```
#Suppose you have some start and end points
start_vector = numpy.array([4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2])
end_vector = numpy.array([-40, 40, -10, -30, 10, 40, 30, -8, 50, 20])

#To get a vector that's located in-between:
intermediate_vector = start_vector + (end_vector - start_vector) * fraction
```

`fraction` is a number between 0 and 1 that determines how far along you are between the start and end (0 puts you at `start_vector`, 1 gives you `end_vector`, and 0.5 gives you the halfway point linearly between those two vectors, etc).